# How is cosmic microwave background radiation experimentally detected?

Tags: cosmic-microwave-background, antennas

Can it be detected from the earth with a single dipole antenna or a series of such antenna forming an interferometer (with an electric circuit to filter out the noise due to radio stations and atmospheric fluctuation)?

Or do we need a more sophisticated detection method?

Comment: The cosmic background _is_ thermal noise. Might be possible with a satellite dish, looking at other directions than the tv-satellite.

Comment: @Pieter I meant noise due to other sources. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ethan (Starts With A Bang!) Siegel says the cosmic microwave background is ["about 1% of the total “snow” signal that you see"](https://medium.com/starts-with-a-bang/this-is-how-your-old-television-set-can-prove-the-big-bang-ca17e6eccc4f) on an old TV.

[image]

Comment: This does not answer how to specifically detect that 1%.

Comment: If you were in intergalactic space (without most the other sources  Siegel mentions) it would be more than $1$%. So you could probably "detect" it, but if you want to prove that it is not coming from galactic sources you need a more directional antenna.